# Using managed dll (which uses unmanaged dll) in c# project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, interop

As the title says, I am using a managed dll (myManaged.dll) in my c# project (myProject). But myManaged.dll makes use of an unmanaged (c++) dll (myUnmanaged.dll).

My question is: Do I need to explicitly load myUnmanaged.dll in myProject along with the method declaration?

And if yes, then should it be like this:

```
[dllImport "myUnmanaged.dll", EntryPoint = "myMethod"]
public extern IntPtr myMethod(int myParam);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need, as long as you are not going to use myUnmanaged.dll directly in myProject